# Conditional nofollow in WordPress footer

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress, I would like to add rel="nofollow" to links that meet the following conditions:-

- the link is external
- the link is NOT on the home page / front page
- the link appears in the footer or specific div in the footer, eg.

  `<div class="creds">`

Any help very much appreciated!

UPDATE: I have managed to enqueue the script as follows:-

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pcaweb_load_javascript_files' );

function pcaweb_load_javascript_files() {

  wp_register_script( 'nofollow', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) .'/js/nofollow.js', array('jquery'), '1.0' );

  if ( !is_front_page() ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('nofollow');
  }

}
```

Now just need to get the JQuery working (see comment below)
Here's the site I'm working on: [link to site](http://www.angpk.co.uk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if (!is_home() && !is_admin()) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var localURL = new RegExp(location.host);

            jQuery('.creds a').each(function(){    
                if(!localURL.test(jQuery(this).attr('href'))) {
                    jQuery(this).attr('rel', 'nofollow');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>       
<?php } ?>
```

Just copy this entire thing inside of `<head></head>`.  I've tested this on a live site, and it works.

Comment: Andy, thanks for this answer. I will definitely play with it. I had tried some php code in the functions.php file previously using `if is_home()` but it wasn't very elegant (or successful!). I'll get back to you once I have it working.

Comment: Andy - I have managed to enqueue the script as follows:- `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pcaweb_load_javascript_files' );

function pcaweb_load_javascript_files() {

  wp_register_script( 'nofollow', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) .'/js/nofollow.js', array('jquery'), '1.0' );
  
  if ( !is_front_page() ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('nofollow');
  }
 
}`

Comment: and the script is loading in the header successfully. The JQuery is not working however, so I have made an error there somewhere! The link I am interested in nofollowing is in a div with class "creds". Other divs on the page are "site-container", "body" etc. Here is a link to the site in question: [link](http://www.angpk.co.uk). The area I'm interested in is the credits in the left column. Pretty close to getting this working...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see that script in your home page source.  You don't necessarily have to mess with trying to enqueue that script, you can just paste it in the header or footer, then adjust the pieces that I posted above.

Comment: Andy, you should see it in every page except for the home page as I added a `!` to the is_front_page()

Comment: Ya, just checked a secondary page, still don't see it.  I also add an `!` to my jQuery above, as I thought you wanted it to only happen on the home page.

Comment: OK - sorry, if you check now, you should see the script loading on any page that isn't the home page. I only want to nofollow the footer links ("creds") if they're not on the home page. Sorry about the confusion - thx for sticking with it, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Let's try this a bit different.  For the sake of testing, do not enqueue this, just paste it inside of `<head></head>`.  I'll edit my answer above.

Comment: Outstanding! It works a treat. I tested by pasting code first, then amended my .js file. All working. Can't thank you enough!